# How to write sub join in HQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I'm new in hibernate and HQL a want to convert this sql to HQL query
cannot Convert Sub Join with sub select to HQL in hibernate

```
     SELECT  m.ID, SUM(CASE WHEN pl.IN_OUT = 1
                       THEN pl.INP
                  ELSE 0 END + 
                  CASE WHEN MRL.IN_OUT = 1
                       THEN MRL.INP
                  ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN sl.IN_OUT = 1
                       THEN sl.INP
                  ELSE 0 END) INP

FROM   MATERIAL                      AS m
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT pl1.MATERIAL_ID, 
                   pl1.IN_OUT, 
                   pl1.WAREHOUSE_ID,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN PL1.IN_OUT = 1 THEN PL1.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) 
        INP, 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN PL1.IN_OUT = 2 THEN PL1.QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) 
          OUTP 
            FROM PURCHASE_LINE pl1
            GROUP BY pl1.MATERIAL_ID, pl1.IN_OUT, pl1.WAREHOUSE_ID
      ) as pl ON PL.MATERIAL_ID = M.ID AND PL.WAREHOUSE_ID = W.ID

     WHERE m.ID = 273607     
  GROUP BY m.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL and JPQL do not support derived tables. You could transform your derived table into several correlated subqueries, but I think you'll just be better off writing a native SQL query.